# How do I monad an arbitrary number of Monads together in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

Let's say I have

```
x :: Monad a => [a]
x = [item1, item2, item3, ...]
```

And I want to do for these:

```
y f = f <$> item1 <*> item2 <*> item3 <*> item4 <*> ...
```

Previously I've tried this for doing it with ZipLists:

```
zipf' x (y:z) = getZipList $ foldl (<*>) (x <$> y) z
```

But it unfortunately returned this:

```
<interactive>:94:36: error:
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 ~ a -> a1
  Expected type: ZipList a1 -> ZipList a -> ZipList a1
    Actual type: ZipList (a -> a1) -> ZipList a -> ZipList a1
• In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘(<*>)’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘foldl (<*>) (x <$> y) z’
  In the expression: getZipList $ foldl (<*>) (x <$> y) z
• Relevant bindings include
    z :: [ZipList a] (bound at <interactive>:94:12)
    y :: ZipList a (bound at <interactive>:94:10)
    x :: a -> a1 (bound at <interactive>:94:7)
    zipf' :: (a -> a1) -> [ZipList a] -> [a1]
      (bound at <interactive>:94:1)
```

Comment: looks like `sequence` to me

Comment: @n.m. You should promote that comment to an answer!

Comment: This isn't really `sequence` at all, is it? We don't want `m [a]`, we want to fold it up, probably with something like `foldM`, but it's hard to tell because the types given in the question are impossible.

Comment: I would avoid trying to do this, because it means `f` needs to accept a variable number of parameters, and that's not usually very practical. Let `f` accept a list as a single parameter instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, values of type `IO a` and `Maybe a`, etc. are not typically called "monads", and calling them that will definitely cause a *lot* of confusion if you are ever asking for help.  The `IO` type and the `Maybe` type themselves are typically called Monads.  Values of type 'IO a' are not monads...there isn't a common word for them, but a some people call them "motes".

Comment: Maybe try to describe what you want to do in higher-level wording.  What you're actually describing here at a low level doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type

```
x :: Monad a => [a]
```

is impossible: you cannot have such a thing, because Monad needs a type parameter. You probably mean

```
x :: Monad m => [m a]
```

After that, the next problem is: what is the type of `y`? It takes a function `f`, and that `f` somehow accepts any number of arguments? That doesn't sound right, which is why GHC is complaining about the infinite type: `f`'s type must contain as a subterm the type of `f` itself.

Perhaps you mean something more like [`foldM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM)? Whether or not `foldM` is what you need after all, your search will be easier once you nail down the correct types of the functions you're after.